# Selecting from div class dropdown - Selenium but its not working

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

I am trying to select an option from a drop-down that does not populate until the locator has been clicked. This my solution but it's not working.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("mat-select"));
                
for (WebElement option : options) {
    if (option.getAttribute("ng-reflect-value").contentEquals("50757")) {
        Actions build = new Actions(driver);
        build.moveToElement(option).click().build().perform();
    }
}
```

HTML of the dropdown.

```html
<div role="listbox" 
     tabindex="-1" 
     class="ng-tns-c114-22 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanel mat-select-panel mat-primary" 
     id="mat-select-0-panel" 
     aria-multiselectable="false"
     aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-27" 
     style="transform-origin: 50% 22px 0px; font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; min-width: calc(100% + 32px); transform: scaleY(1);">
    <mat-option 
            _ngcontent-tqo-c274="" 
            role="option" 
            class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator mat-active ng-tns-c114-22 ng-star-inserted" 
            ng-reflect-value="50757" 
            id="mat-option-0" 
            tabindex="0"
```

Comment: <div role="listbox" tabindex="-1" class="ng-tns-c114-22 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanel mat-select-panel mat-primary" id="mat-select-0-panel" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-27" style="transform-origin: 50% 22px 0px; font-size: 15px; opacity: 1; min-width: calc(100% + 32px); transform: scaleY(1);"><mat-option _ngcontent-tqo-c274="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator mat-active ng-tns-c114-22 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-value="50757" id="mat-option-0" tabindex="0" :: HTML of the dropdown.

Comment: <span class="mat-option-text"> Test User </span> --> This is the user that I want to click on

Comment: Commenting lengthy code snippets is not a way to explain your problem. Please edit your question again if you want to add more content

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code: If possible please share the application URL then I can replicate it from my side.

```
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat- 
      option[contains(text(),'option text')]");
driver.waitUntilElementVisible(option, 10); 
driver.findElement(option).click();
```

Also please refer [link](https://biswasarpita.medium.com/selecting-dropdown-option-with-selenium-19ef06e1d5fa) for more details on selecting a particular value in a dropdown without using the methods of Select class in Selenium